# Why do I get a division by zero error when typing MsgBox(0.5 mod 0.1) in the immediate window?

Tags: excel, vba

Why do I get a division by zero error when typing MsgBox(0.5 mod 0.1) in the immediate window?

When I type Mod(0.5,0.1) in an Excel spreadsheet I get 0,1

Comment: `If either number is a floating-point number, it is first rounded to an integer.` - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264708(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because VBA's `Mod` only works with integers. So you're basically doing *something* `MOD 0`, which results in a division by zero.

The `Mod()` function in the Excel engine is not the `MOD` function in VBA.

Comment: That's surprising. I thought MOD was basically always the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can access Excel `Mod` function from VBA with `Evaluate`:

```
Evaluate("Mod(0.5,0.1)")
```